# Does APA style satisfy AEA style requirements?

Tags: citation-style, graphics, formatting, tables

I see the [AEA templates](https://www.aeaweb.org/journals/policies/templates) as well as [APA guidelines](https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/research_and_citation/apa_style/apa_formatting_and_style_guide/general_format.html). I'm in the process of assessing the question myself, but I'm wondering if anyone has a quick answer: If I format my paper according to APA guidelines will this also satisfy AEA style requirements?

To add context to a paper I'm working on: I do have tables and equations, but I do not have second or third level headings. Only first-level headings.

I'm interested in contributing this work [PubCSS](https://github.com/thomaspark/pubcss) and I'm wondering if I will need two distinct style sheets, or if I can get away with a single one. It would be even better if I can get away with 0 new style sheets! PubCSS already supports ACM and IEEE style, so if anyone is familiar with those then I would be curious what differences, if any, exist between those, APA, and AEA.

Comment: tentative finding: AEA and IEEE both use Chicago Style: https://github.com/thomaspark/pubcss/issues/20

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, [AEA uses a modified Chicago style](https://www.aeaweb.org/journals/policies/sample-references). APA formatting will not meet this criteria. PubCSS is currently some distance from being able to implement an AEA paper in CSS. At the moment, I recommend sticking with the AEA-provided LaTeX template.